# Pattern for multiplicity in python

Tags: python-2.7

In my Python application I have the concept of multiplicity stored as a tuple in a class. This multiplicity has kind of the same meaning as it is in UML syntax, so it will say how many objects of that class may be instantiated.

To set its values, I have a method `myClass.setMethod(multiplicity)`, where multiplicity is a tuple and inside this method I would like to verify if the user has provided correct lower and upper values for the tuple.

Valid examples:

```
(1,1)
(0,1)
(1,6)
(0,*)
(0,-1)
```

Invalid examples:

```
(-1,3)
(0,-2)
(2,1)
```

Basically I need to check if all the 3 following statements are respected:

- The lower value is an integer number >=0
- The upper value is an integer number >= -1 or the character *.
- lower is <= upper
  (Leaving the possibility to specify this case as well(0,0))

I was thinking that a possible way would be using regular expressions.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you tell how (0,-1) is valid?

Comment: Are those tuples of strings, or just strings, or what? I.e., is it `(0,'*')`, or `('0','*')`, or `'(0,*)'`?

Comment: @WannaBeCoder: I guess that the upper end is inclusive here, so it's a way of representing an empty range of integers: all `n` such that `0 <= n <= -1`.  (The analogue of `range(0, 0)`.)

Comment: @Simo: it might be more Pythonic to use `None` instead of `*` for the upper bound.

Comment: With -1 as upper value I would like to express the same as *. The same syntax UML tools use for representing the "to-many" multiplicity. Those are tuples of integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are explicitly asking for a solution with regular expressions, I will assume that those "tuples" are in fact *string-representations* of tuples.

First, let's create a regex for the "tuples", holding a non-negative number, followed by a comma and optional space, and then another non-negative number or a wildcard.

```
p = re.compile(r"\((\d+)\,\s*(\d+|-1|\*)\)")
```

Then first check whether that regex matches, and then just check whether the upper bound is a wildcard (`*` or `-1`) or the lower is smaller or equal than the upper bound.

```
def check(string):
    m = p.match(string)
    if m:
        lower, upper = m.groups()
        if upper in ("*", "-1"):
            return True
        else:
            return int(lower) <= int(upper)
    else:
        return False
```

You test cases:

```
>>> all(map(check, ['(1,1)', '(0,1)', '(1,6)', '(0,*)', '(0,-1)']))
True
>>> not any(map(check, ['(-1,3)', '(0,-2)', '(2,1)']))
True
```

Or if those are *actually* tuples of integers and `'*'`, use this:

```
def check(tuple_):
    try:
        lower, upper = tuple_
        return isinstance(lower, int) and int(lower) >= 0 and \
               (upper in ('*', -1) or isinstance(upper, int) and int(lower) <= int(upper)) 
    except:
        return False
```

Tests:

```
>>> all(map(check, [(1,1), (0,1), (1,6), (0,'*'), (0,-1)]))
True
>>> not any(map(check, [(-1,3), (0,-2), (2,1)]))
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for. So now I have rewritten the check method to handle the 2 different multiplicity formats (tuple, string) and give the possibility to use both to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I simply rewrote your conditions. Some tuple unpacking and simple conditionals.

```
def isValid(t):
    if len(t) != 2:
        return False
    lower, upper = t[0], t[1]
    if lower < 0:
        return False
    if upper == "*":
        return True
    if upper < -2 or upper < lower:
        return False
    return True

assert isValid((1,1))
assert isValid((0,1))
assert isValid((1,6))
assert isValid((0,'*'))
assert not isValid((0,-1))  # I guess it was your mistake, as clearly 0 > -1
assert not isValid((-1,3))
assert not isValid((0,-2))
assert not isValid((2,1))
```